# Badly installed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, usb-drive

Today, I have decided to make a new partition of my HDD and then to install Ubuntu 14.04. I have already had Windows installed on another partition. I installed Ubuntu and the installation has been finished successfully.

After rebooting the system, the OS selection screen didn't come up, and it started to boot Windows immediately with an error. So I couldn't boot Windows, because I have probably rewritten some of the system data. Then I have tried to change the boot sequence to boot at Ubuntu. I can boot Ubuntu from the USB now, and the Ubuntu data are saved on the HDD. However, I'm still not able to boot it without the USB flash disk plugged in.

Another problem is that anything I change does not save and when I reboot Ubuntu it's gone. For example I have to download VLC every time I run the laptop.

I don't expect you to help me to run Windows because I am pretty sure that I can't do that without the installation CD but I would be glad if you could tell me how to make Ubuntu bootable even without the USB plugged in and how to fix the not saving settings issue.

This is what I get when I write this prompt: `sudo fdisk -l`

```
 Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x9fd8fea1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63        2047         992+  42  SFS
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2   *        2048      616447      307200   42  SFS
/dev/sda3          616448  1009506303   504444928   42  SFS
/dev/sda4      1009508350  1465147391   227819521    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1009508352  1465147391   227819520   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 4004 MB, 4004024320 bytes
32 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3879 cylinders, total 7820360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x16c32dd7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63     7820063     3910000+   b  W95 FAT32
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ^C
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried running [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)?

Comment: i have not, can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: I linked a guide in my first comment. Basically, boot into the Ubuntu USB Live, install boot-repair, and run boot-repair. See if it fixes your lack of a GRUB screen (choose between Ubuntu and Windows menu) at boot.

Comment: @JakubNosek: If you use Ubuntu from the USB, nothing is going to be saved. That's by design.

Comment: +1 for boot repair. Saves me from this trouble all the time.

Comment: Boot repair fixed all the issues with UBUNTU, thanks @CarrotIsland!

Comment: Hey @JakubNosek, if you would be so kind, could you accept my answer below? It is what I stated above and will improve clarity for future readers as well as officially mark this question as **answered**. [Answer Acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Basically, boot into the Ubuntu USB Live, install boot-repair, and run boot-repair. (Moved into an answer to make it clear for future readers)